# Pywin32 : How to enable pywin to evaluate -X utf8 flag

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

I need to start my python application through windows service. For this purpose I use pywin32.
I'm not able to make a Python instance to evaluate the -X uf8 flag.

This flag must be passed during python invocation only and not when it is already started.
After some investigations I've found the service launch pythonservice.exe wrapper but I don't know how to pass the flag to the Python interpreter.

Is there another option to set this flag? It is possible to set an env variable PYTHONUTF8=1  but pythonservice.exe doesn't seem to evaluate it...

My environment

- Windows 11 Home 22H2
- Python 3.11.1 (tags/v3.11.1:a7a450f, Dec  6 2022, 19:43:28) [MSC v.1934 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
- Pywin32 305
- Pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0

PyWin32 developer told me to try this
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/blob/main/win32/Demos/service/nativePipeTestService.py
but it doesn't work because it doesn't use pythonservice.exe but wrap python application on service directly.

**Python documentation**

> 4.7. UTF-8 mode¶
> New in version 3.7.
>
> Windows still uses legacy encodings for the system encoding (the ANSI Code Page). Python uses it for the default encoding of text files (e.g. locale.getencoding()).
>
> This may cause issues because UTF-8 is widely used on the internet and most Unix systems, including WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
>
> You can use the Python UTF-8 Mode to change the default text encoding to UTF-8. You can enable the Python UTF-8 Mode via the -X utf8 command line option, or the PYTHONUTF8=1 environment variable. See PYTHONUTF8 for enabling UTF-8 mode, and Excursus: Setting environment variables for how to modify environment variables.
>
> When the Python UTF-8 Mode is enabled, you can still use the system encoding (the ANSI Code Page) via the “mbcs” codec.
>
> Note that adding PYTHONUTF8=1 to the default environment variables will affect all Python 3.7+ applications on your system. If you have any Python 3.7+ applications which rely on the legacy system encoding, it is recommended to set the environment variable temporarily or use the -X utf8 command line option.
>
> Note   Even when UTF-8 mode is disabled, Python uses UTF-8 by default on Windows for:
> Console I/O including standard I/O (see PEP 528 for details).
>
> The filesystem encoding (see PEP 529 for details).

from -> https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks in advance